# How to distinguish makefile and Xcode project generation phases in qmake for iOS apps?

Tags: ios, xcode, qmake

Qt 5.15, an iOS app. By default, qmake generates Xcode project files as well. And actually app's pro-file is processed twice by qmake: in makefile and Xcode project modes. I think it's true, because in both cases build_pass == 0.

How can one distinguish that modes? Perfectly, some difference in the scope, like 'macx-xcode' scope for macOS apps.

Answer (score 0):

'macx-xcode' works for iOS targets too. So, there is trivial:

```
macx-xcode: message("We are in Xcode project generation phase")
```

Now, I have the question issued: For iOS and macOS targets how can one force qmake to generate/skip Xcode project geeration?